# Nested Inner Join with identically named columns?

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to come up with a SQL query string to read information from three tables, where they have overlapping column names:

```
Table: Task
Id
TaskDescription
...

Table: TaskAttempt
Id
TaskId
User
...

Table: TaskSubmission
Id
TaskAttemptId
Data
...
```

A task contains a description. Users can attempt to complete the task and they submit their results. Each task attempt can have multiple submissions.

When reviewing, I want to pull in all task submissions and display the description, user, and data; I also need to pull in all the Id fields so that I can update the rows upon review completion.

What would a SQL statement look like to capture this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with column names that are the same in different tables, you have to prefix the columns with the table that you are requesting the data from. This is a VERY basic shell of what your query would look like. The `JOIN` statements need the corresponding columns, but you did not provide the schema on how they match up. However, this answers your basic question about columns with the same name.

```
SELECT Task.Id, Task.TaskDescription, TaskAttempt.Id, TaskAttempt.User, 
    TaskSubmission.Id, TaskSubmission.Data
FROM Task
   JOIN TaskAttempt
       ON Task.Id = TaskAttempt.TaskId
   JOIN TaskSubmission
       ON TaskAttempt.Id = TaskSubmission.TaskAttempId
```

Prefixes simply give the SQL engine enough extra data to know how to handle ambiguities, and they also can provide much more expressive code to future readers.

Comment: I added the foreign key fields. Does this work if I make it JOIN TaskAttempt ON Task.Id = TaskAttempt.TaskId JOIN TaskSubmission ON TaskAttempt.Id = TaskSubmission.TaskAttemptId?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which table to pull from using `table_name.field`, so:

```
SELECT Task.Id, TaskAttempt.Id, TaskSubmission.Id
FROM Task, TaskAttempt, TaskSubmission
```

You get the point. It is a good idea to use the table name on all fields whenever you are dealing with multiple tables. Example:

```
SELECT Task.Id, Task.TaskDescripton, TaskAttempt.Id...
FROM ...
```

Even though `TaskDescription` does not exist in the other tables, I still use the table name for clarity.